# Add each element of the first array to each element of a second array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I would like to write something that creates 100 names of people based on two arrays of first and second names.

```
first_name = ['Tom', 'John', 'Allan', 'Steven', 'Robert', 'Lucy','Ruth', 'Anna', 'Edith', 'Jessica']
second_name = ['Ross', 'Smith', 'Jones', "Wells", "Bain", "Gillespie", "Sutton", "Pearce", "Johnstone", "Lightbody"]
```

I would like it to cycle through the first names, adding each of the second names before moving on to the second `first_name`.

I tried to use the mapping method but got error messages.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please give an example of desired output.

Comment: Your question does not really make clear what answer you want. Do you want an array that returns every name combination, or just the combinations at the same positions.

You question implies thata you want every combination, because your example is 10 first names and 10 last names and you want 10 names. But the answer you commented on as helpful actually provides you only the combinations that match the position.

Comment: "got error messages" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. What is the error message? What trouble do you have with your code? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve]

Comment: By the way: did you look at the documentation? Hint: there is a method whose name is *exactly* the operation you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

You could do...

```
first_name.zip(second_name).map{|n|n.join(' ')}
```

Zip creates an array of arrays: [['Tom', 'Ross'], ['John', 'Smith']...]

The join on each element changes ['Tom', 'Ross'] into 'Tom Ross'

If you want to do it through more traditional looping use `each_with_index` and use the index of the element in the first array to find the corresponding last name in the second array.

```
result = []
first_name.each_with_index do |name, i|
  result << "#{name} #{last_name[i]}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that, I know its a bit of a simple question but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
first_name.map do |fname|
  second_name.map do |sname|
    "#{fname} #{sname}"
  end
end.flatten
#=> ["Tom Ross", "Tom Smith", "Tom Jones", "Tom Wells", "Tom Bain", "Tom Gillespie", "Tom Sutton", "Tom Pearce", "Tom Johnstone", "Tom Lightbody", "John Ross", "John Smith", "John Jones", "John Wells", "John Bain", "John Gillespie", "John Sutton", "John Pearce", "John Johnstone", "John Lightbody", "Allan Ross", "Allan Smith", "Allan Jones", "Allan Wells", "Allan Bain", "Allan Gillespie", "Allan Sutton", "Allan Pearce", "Allan Johnstone", "Allan Lightbody", "Steven Ross", "Steven Smith", "Steven Jones", "Steven Wells", "Steven Bain", "Steven Gillespie", "Steven Sutton", "Steven Pearce", "Steven Johnstone", "Steven Lightbody", "Robert Ross", "Robert Smith", "Robert Jones", "Robert Wells", "Robert Bain", "Robert Gillespie", "Robert Sutton", "Robert Pearce", "Robert Johnstone", "Robert Lightbody", "Lucy Ross", "Lucy Smith", "Lucy Jones", "Lucy Wells", "Lucy Bain", "Lucy Gillespie", "Lucy Sutton", "Lucy Pearce", "Lucy Johnstone", "Lucy Lightbody", "Ruth Ross", "Ruth Smith", "Ruth Jones", "Ruth Wells", "Ruth Bain", "Ruth Gillespie", "Ruth Sutton", "Ruth Pearce", "Ruth Johnstone", "Ruth Lightbody", "Anna Ross", "Anna Smith", "Anna Jones", "Anna Wells", "Anna Bain", "Anna Gillespie", "Anna Sutton", "Anna Pearce", "Anna Johnstone", "Anna Lightbody", "Edith Ross", "Edith Smith", "Edith Jones", "Edith Wells", "Edith Bain", "Edith Gillespie", "Edith Sutton", "Edith Pearce", "Edith Johnstone", "Edith Lightbody", "Jessica Ross", "Jessica Smith", "Jessica Jones", "Jessica Wells", "Jessica Bain", "Jessica Gillespie", "Jessica Sutton", "Jessica Pearce", "Jessica Johnstone", "Jessica Lightbody"]
```